# Sending messages with facebook xmpp api

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I have copied and modified some of the facebook's given chat api code, now I want to send a message to my friend. I found that we send a xml `<message from="" to="">` to send a message. But that did not happen. maybe it's because i don't know what to put on `from` and `to` attribs?

The Code:

```
<?php
$STREAM_XML = '<stream:stream '.
  'xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" '.
  'version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" to="chat.facebook.com" '.
  'xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">';

$AUTH_XML = '<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" '.
  'mechanism="X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM"></auth>';

$CLOSE_XML = '</stream:stream>';

$RESOURCE_XML = '<iq type="set" id="3">'.
  '<bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">'.
  '<resource>fb_xmpp_script</resource></bind></iq>';

$SESSION_XML = '<iq type="set" id="4" to="chat.facebook.com">'.
  '<session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>';

$START_TLS = '<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>';

$MESSAGE = '<message from="-cyberkiller.nishchal@chat.facebook.com" to="-nootan.ghimire@chat.facebook.com">
    <body>This is the test message! Sent from App. by, "Nishchal"</body>
</message>';

function open_connection($server) {
  $fp = fsockopen($server, 5222, $errno, $errstr);
  if (!$fp) {
    print "$errstr ($errno)<br>";
  } else {
    print "connnection open<br>";
  }
  return $fp;
}
function send_xml($fp, $xml) {
  fwrite($fp, $xml);
}
function recv_xml($fp,  $size=4096) {
  $xml = fread($fp, $size);
  if (!preg_match('/^</', $xml)) {
    $xml = '<' . $xml;
  }
  if ($xml === "") {
     return null;
  }

  $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
  xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xml, $val, $index);
  xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
  return array($val, $index);
}
function find_xmpp($fp,  $tag, $value=null, &$ret=null) {
  static $val = null, $index = null;
  do {
    if ($val === null && $index === null) {
      list($val, $index) = recv_xml($fp);
      if ($val === null || $index === null) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    foreach ($index as $tag_key => $tag_array) {
      if ($tag_key === $tag) {
        if ($value === null) {
          if (isset($val[$tag_array[0]]['value'])) {
            $ret = $val[$tag_array[0]]['value'];
          }
          return true;
        }
        foreach ($tag_array as $i => $pos) {
          if ($val[$pos]['tag'] === $tag && isset($val[$pos]['value']) &&
            $val[$pos]['value'] === $value) {
              $ret = $val[$pos]['value'];
              return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $val = $index = null;
  } while (!feof($fp));
  return false;
}
function xmpp_connect($options, $access_token) {
  global $STREAM_XML, $AUTH_XML, $RESOURCE_XML, $SESSION_XML, $CLOSE_XML, $START_TLS;
  $fp = open_connection($options['server']);
  if (!$fp) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp,  $STREAM_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'STREAM:STREAM')) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!find_xmpp($fp,  'MECHANISM', 'X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp,  $START_TLS);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'PROCEED', null, $proceed)) {
    return false;
  }
  stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
  send_xml($fp, $STREAM_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'STREAM:STREAM')) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'MECHANISM', 'X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp, $AUTH_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp,  'CHALLENGE', null, $challenge)) {
    return false;
  }
  $challenge = base64_decode($challenge);
  $challenge = urldecode($challenge);
  parse_str($challenge, $challenge_array);
  $resp_array = array(
    'method' => $challenge_array['method'],
    'nonce' => $challenge_array['nonce'],
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'api_key' => $options['app_id'],
    'call_id' => 0,
    'v' => '1.0',
  );
  $response = http_build_query($resp_array);
  $xml = '<response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">'.
    base64_encode($response).'</response>';
  send_xml($fp, $xml);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'SUCCESS')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp, $STREAM_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp,'STREAM:STREAM')) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'STREAM:FEATURES')) {
    return false;
  }
 send_xml($fp, $RESOURCE_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'JID')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp, $SESSION_XML);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'SESSION')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp, $MESSAGE);
  if (!find_xmpp($fp, 'BODY')) {
    return false;
  }
  send_xml($fp, $CLOSE_XML);
  print ("Authentication complete<br>");
  fclose($fp);
  return true;
}
function get_access_token(){
$token=new Facebook(array("AppId"=>"my app id","AppSecret"=>"my app secret"));
$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
return $token;
}
function _main() {
  require_once("facebook.php");
  $app_id='app id';
  $app_secret='app secret';
  $my_url = "http://localhost/message.php";
  $uid = 'cyberkiller.nishchal@chat.facebook.com';
  $access_token = get_access_token();
  $options = array(
    'uid' => $uid,
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'server' => 'chat.facebook.com',
   );
  if (xmpp_connect($options, $access_token)) {
    print "Done<br>";
  } else {
    print "An error ocurred<br>";
  }
}
_main();
```

so what do I need to do to send a message to that user through this, i tried to create a xml with the message but got strucked there, can any one please suggest something, When I run the code, socket enable crypto is being executed after that it is taking some time like 20 secs, then it displays an error occured, do I have to remove the `send_xml($fp,$STREAM_XML);` for the second time after the `stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, false, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);`
I changed the second parameter of this call to false because I don't have an ssl connection, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Facebook ID instead of the url username.Get it by requesting http://graph.facebook.com/{username}
Then replace it on "from" and "to" attributes.Also remove the hyphen on "from" attribute, or just remove all of it (from my experience its still going to work).Hyphen on "to" attribute is mandatory.

Comment: @Wazzzy I think they have disabled it by now, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988889/replacement-for-facebook-chat-api-in-v2-0